# How can I separate css files from public and admin area components?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I need to separate bootstrap (v3 and v4) files for Public area and Admin dashboard.

I am using **bootstrap 4** based theme in public area and **bootstrap 3** based theme in admin dashboard (AdminLTE).

I created this app using angular CLI tool.
Now all `css` file placed in **angular-cli.js**
and two folders called **admin** (all admin dashboard components) and **site** (all public area components) in **app** folder.

How can I separate these asset files for both admin area components?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Shadow DOM encapsulation for your components

[doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Comment: Thnk you.., Its worked. I used  **encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None**